# Getting Error: Framework 'Mono / .NET 4.0' not installed. In MonoDevelop / Mac on a new project

Tags: macos, .net-4.0, mono, monodevelop

I have installed Mono 2.10.8 (that should have .NET 4 support) and MonoDevelop 2.8.6.4 on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

I created a new project, but now the IDE displays this error: `Error: Framework 'Mono / .NET 4.0' not installed. (Project name)`.

What do I need to do in order to be able to compile the project?

Comment: Never mind. After I tried 'turning it off an on again' (= restarting MonoDevelop) the project compiles.

Comment: lol - I had the same problem and your fix worked...  You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I post this as answer:

MonoDevelop has to be restarted after it updated itself to work with the new .NET 4 features.